# R: subset data.frame based on column value using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
mydat1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                    Gender = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male"),
                    Score = c(30, 40, 20, 60))
mydat1 %>%
  group_by(ID, Gender) %>%
  slice(which.min(Score))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID, Gender [3]
     ID Gender Score
  <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>
1     1 Female    40
2     1   Male    30
3     2   Male    20
```

I'm trying to group the rows by `ID` and `Gender`. And then I want to only keep the row with the lowest `Score`. The above code works perfectly because when `ID == 2`, I only kept the entry with the lower score.

```
mydat2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
                    Gender = c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male"),
                    Score = c(NA, NA, 20, 60))

mydat2 %>%
  group_by(ID, Gender) %>%
  slice(which.min(Score))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   ID, Gender [1]
     ID Gender Score
  <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>
1     2   Male    20
```

However, when I have NAs, `which.min` doesn't work like I want it to because it'll not return a valid index. Instead, all of my `ID == 1` entries are erased. My desired output in this scenario is:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   ID, Gender [1]
     ID Gender Score
  <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>
1     1 Female    NA
2     1   Male    NA
1     2   Male    20
```

How can I modify my code to account for this?

Edit:

```
df2 <- structure(list(pubmed_id = c(23091106L, 23091106L), Gender = structure(c(4L, 
                                                                                4L), .Label = c("", "Both", "female", "Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), 
                      Total_Carrier = c(NA, 1107)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
                                                              "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), vars = "pubmed_id", drop = TRUE, indices = list(
                                                                0:1), group_sizes = 2L, biggest_group_size = 2L, labels = structure(list(
                                                                  pubmed_id = 23091106L), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                              -1L), vars = "pubmed_id", drop = TRUE, .Names = "pubmed_id"), .Names = c("pubmed_id", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                       "Gender", "Total_Carrier"))

> df2
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   pubmed_id [1]
  pubmed_id Gender Total_Carrier
      <int> <fctr>         <dbl>
1  23091106 Female            NA
2  23091106 Female          1107
```

In this example, I would want the desired output to only contain row 2 (i.e. the row with carrier sample size of 1107). However, I get the following result:

```
> df2 %>%
   group_by(pubmed_id, Gender) %>%
   slice(which.min(Total_Carrier) || 1)

# A tibble: 1 x 3
# Groups:   pubmed_id, Gender [1]
  pubmed_id Gender Total_Carrier
      <int> <fctr>         <dbl>
1  23091106 Female            NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`which.min` ignores the missing values, and returns `integer(0)` when the input vector contains solely `NA`s. You can add a condition check in the `slice`, i.e.  when all Scores are `NA`s in a group, pick the first row:

```
mydat2 %>%
     group_by(ID, Gender) %>%
     slice({idx <- which.min(Score); if(length(idx) > 0) idx else 1})

# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID, Gender [3]
#     ID Gender Score
#  <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>
#1     1 Female    NA
#2     1   Male    NA
#3     2   Male    20
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `arrange` to sort your scores within your groups, and then `slice` to select the first row of each group. That way, if there are only NAs in the group, you would still select the first row:

```
mydat2 %>%
group_by(ID, Gender) %>%
arrange(ID,Gender,Score) %>%
slice(1)
     ID Gender Score
  <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>
1     1 Female    NA
2     1   Male    NA
3     2   Male    20
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option with `which` and `pmin`

```
mydat2 %>%
   group_by(ID, Gender) %>% 
   slice(pmin(1, which(Score == min(Score, na.rm = TRUE))[1], na.rm = TRUE))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   ID, Gender [3]
#      ID Gender Score
#   <dbl> <fctr> <dbl>
#1     1 Female    NA
#2     1   Male    NA
#3     2   Male    20
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydat2)
mydat2[, .(Score = sort(Score)[1]), by = .(ID, Gender)]
#    ID Gender Score
# 1:  1   Male    NA
# 2:  1 Female    NA
# 3:  2   Male    20
```